# PHP header('Content-Type : image/jpeg') works on localhost but not working on real server

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I want to hide the image url from users, so I am using php `header()` function, the problem raises when I host my website on Bluehost, it works fine on localhost.
here is my function to access the image.

```
function download($name = '', $tiny = '0') {
    if ($name != '') {
        $file = $this->mdl->get_file($name);
        if($file){
                $mime = mime_content_type('./'.$file->path.$file->name);
                header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
                echo file_get_contents('./'.$file->path.$file->name);
        }
    }
}
```

here is get_file function on model:

```
function get_file($name=''){
    if($name!=''){
        return $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('docs')
        ->where('name',$name)
        ->get()
        ->row();
    }
    return false;
}
```

any helpfull answer is appretiated.

Comment: What is happening at bluehost? Any kind of error?

Comment: the following error arises when I want to see the image using Mozilla : the image "http://www.mywebsitename.com/index.php/main/download/1234556.jpg" can not be displayed because it contains errors. but when I use Chrom browser it only shows a small box instead of image.  @Gabriel Heming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this type of problem occur when any space or new line exist out of the php tags or anything printed before the header function.

- Try this :

**ob_clean();** before the header

Answer (score 1):

Headers could only be set before any data is send to the browser.

Check for spaces before your `<?php` tag.

Check if your file is saved as UTF-8 without BOM, the BO-marker could be interpreted as output.

Check if your hoster adds additional content/headers to your page.

Comment: This should be questions in comments, not an answer, since we have no idea if any of these things is relevant with his current set up.

Comment: the header() works for 'Content-type : application/pdf' but gives error for 'Content-type : image/...'